Freeradius. Remove 'Message-Authenticator' from Accept-Reply
I have freeradius docker image
How to remove attribute "Message-Authenticator" from "Access-Reply"?
Here is the final part from debug log
(0)   post-auth {
(0)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && 
(reply:User-Name == request:User-Name)) {
(0)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && 
(reply:User-Name == request:User-Name))  -> FALSE
(0)     update {
(0)       No attributes updated for RHS &session-state:
(0)     } # update = noop
(0)     [exec] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id) {
(0)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id)  -> FALSE
(0)   } # post-auth = noop
(0) Login OK: [alice_cne/testing123] (from client localhost port 0)
(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 165 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:60248 length 76
(0)   Reply-Message = "secAdmin"

so, here i don't see any "Message-Authenticator" attribute, but in the final response from radtest i'v got
radtest alice_cne testing123 127.0.0.1 0 testing123

Sent Access-Request Id 137 from 0.0.0.0:33567 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 79
User-Name = "alice_cne"
User-Password = "testing123"
NAS-IP-Address = 172.16.0.2
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00
Cleartext-Password = "testing123"
Received Access-Accept Id 137 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:33567 length 76
Message-Authenticator = 0x8cafe05c5f22c9f535ace4738ac2cbb3
Reply-Message = "secAdmin"

Try to disable this in radiusd.conf, but still not effect
require_message_authenticator = no


I believe this is permanently enabled now.  Why do you want to remove it?

integration with our devices

You can try adding the below in the post-auth section of the /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default file
if (reply:Message-Authenticator) {
        update reply {
            Message-Authenticator !* ANY
        }
    }


It'd work for older versions.  But Message-Authenticator is added as a post processing step in 3.2.x and 4.x, it really is hardcoded on.
